# Does my proxied server need to use HTTPS protocol with docker linking?

Tags: security, nginx, docker

I am running several docker containers for a very small web app: nginx, node, and redis. These containers are all linked together using the legacy methods (not a network) with the pattern

`nginx --proxies-> node --uses-> redis`

My nginx proxy is set up to use HTTPS but my node server (using hapi.js) is not. Is this a security issue?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't security  issue if you aren't sending your data from nginx to node using public networks. If your HTTP traffic will be transfered inside one host machine and this host machine is fully controlling by you it will be unreachable for external access.